# Need the visual basic function that remove extra lines

Tags: vba

I need the visual basic function that remove extra lines. As same as the screenshot. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCcLB.jpg)

Comment: This isn't a code writing service.  The post from Ashok, you could of added your comments yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim s As String
s = "That long string..."
While (s <> s.Replace(VbNewLine + VbNewLine, VbNewLine)
s = s.Replace(VbNewLine + VbNewLine, VbNewLine);
Loop
```

Comment: Need function like as:

Function RemoveExtraLines() - - - - - - - End Function

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what you're asking.

```
Public Function RemoveEmptyLines(ByVal Value As String) As String
    RemoveEmptyLines = Replace(Value, vbLf & vbCr, vbNullString)
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, above function is working properly, but its removing all lines. Only single line should remain if more that two extra lines between two lines. Hope you are understanding. Thanks for your supports!